# With json.net, is there a shortish way to manipulate all string fields?

Tags: json.net

Given an arbitrary Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject, if you want to apply some function to all string values that appear in it (wherever that may be) - whether as a basic value of a property, or in an array in the json, what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple way to do this is to use [`JContainer.DescendantsAndSelf()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_DescendantsAndSelf.htm) to find all descendants of the root `JObject` that are string values, then replace the value with a remapped string using [`JToken.Replace()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Replace.htm):

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JToken MapStringValues(this JContainer root, Func<string, string> func)
    {
        foreach (var value in root.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JValue>().Where(v => v.Type == JTokenType.String).ToList())
            value.Replace((JValue)func((string)value.Value));
        return root;
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
jObj.MapStringValues(s => "remapped " + s);
```

Comment: that is really slick