# Remove trailing spaces in json string c#

Tags: c#, json, regex

I have a large json string that I need to remove any number of leading and trailing spaces from property values (in c#) e.g.

```
"Some Property Name": " Some Value "
```

needs to change to:-

```
"Some Property Name": "Some Value"
```

I have the option to do this via a regex replace on the json string before it is converted into a newtonsoft json object, or loop through the json object's properties after it has been converted.

Anybody any thoughts on the best way to do this?

Comment: Not knowing the structure of the json, after seems easiest to me. Let the library do the parsing.

Comment: Is the json large? Are there lots of string properties on the object? Can you define "best"?

Comment: Since you wrote that you are using newtonsoft, see [With json.net, is there a shortish way to manipulate all string fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46148971/3744182).

Comment: Do it within the class that would have such a responsibility within your architecture.  By that I mean you need to consider whether white space would ever be something that you might want to return as a valid value.  If it is for values provided to some classes but not to others then it is perhaps the role of the consuming class, but if you really never want leading/trailing/complete whitespace then you may as well do it in the reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second option is the safest one.

Any time that you have to modify a structured text of some kind (XML, HTML, JSON, C#, etc.) the safest option is to parse, modify, and re-format. Otherwise, you run the risk of changing things that you did not plan to change.

In your particular scenario a regex solution may unintentionally strip leading spaces from quoted strings inside a string, for example

```
"Some Property Name": " Say \"   Hello, world!\" two times "
```

Corner cases like this often go unnoticed when developing a regex-based solution. On the other hand, parser-based solutions do not treat these situations as "corner cases," because all the complexity of understanding the format is shifted into the parser.