# How to change all empty strings to null when parsing JSON to a JToken

Tags: c#, json

In C#, using JSON.Net and without using custom classes, how would I convert empty strings to nulls? such that:

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstname":"", "lastname":"Doe"},
    {"firstname":"Anna", "lastname":""},
    {"firstname":"", "lastname":"Jones"} 
]}
```

becomes

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstname":null, "lastname":"Doe"},
    {"firstname":"Anna", "lastname":null},
    {"firstname":null, "lastname":"Jones"} 
]}
```

Comment: I found JSON.Net so disappointing and messy I ended up writing my own parser. It was so easy, I did it while driving a loaded school bus on the interstate.

Comment: Why not write a JsonConverter?

Comment: I guess my question is why would you need to? Will null be pass down client side?

Comment: You could adapt the answer from [With json.net, is there a shortish way to manipulate all string fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46148971) and return `null` from the `func` when the incoming string is empty.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing it this way.
`code`
  public static JToken EmptyStringToNull(this JContainer root)
        {
            if (root == null) return null;

            foreach (var value in root.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JValue>().Where(v => v.Type == JTokenType.String).ToList())
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value.Value))
                {
                    value.Replace(null);
                }
            }

            return root;
        }

Comment: @Ganesh - you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you want, rather than putting the answer in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DefaultValueHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm) options for the JsonSerializer + [DefaultValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cws2s9d) attribute.

Model example:

```
public class User 
{
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string Firstname {get; set; }
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string Lastname {get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization usage example:

```
var json = "{\"firstname\":\"\", \"lastname\":\"Doe\"}";

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore });

Console.WriteLine(obj.Firstname == null); // print out "True"
Console.WriteLine(obj.Firstname == string.Empty); //print out "False"
```