# How to go through each element of a json and update its value in C#?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net

I need to update each and every field of this json. Is there any way in C# to iterate each element and update.

```json
{
   "data":[
      {
         "MSHElements":{
            "MSH.1_FieldSeperator":"",
            "MSH.2_EncodingCharacters":"",
            "MSH.3_SendingApplication":{
               "HD.1_NamespaceId":"",
               "HD.2_UniversalId":"",
               "HD.3_UniversalIdType":""
            }
         },
         "EVNElements":{
            "EVN.1_EvenTypeCode":"",
            "EVN.2_RecordedDateTime":{
               "TS.1_TimeOfAnEvent":"",
               "TS.2_DegreeofPrecision":"99"
            },
            "EVN.3_DateTimePlannedEvent":{
               "TS.1_TimeOfAnEvent":"",
               "TS.2_DegreeofPrecision":"99"
            },
            "EVN.4_EventReasonCode":""
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Which serialization library are you using? Json.NET or System.Text.Json or other?

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: If you want to replace every field would it make sense to create a new one instead?

Comment: I would suggest migrating your solution to System.Text.Json. It saves you a NuGet package and is a more approachable solution.

Comment: As for your problem, Directly editing your JSON in-file is error-prone and not very safe. Your JSON is too inconsistent to parse into POCO, so I would say parse into a Dictionary<string,object> and iterate through that.

Comment: Another option is to add the prefix on property setter and remove it back on property getter if you need too

Comment: What kind of "update" to each "value" do you want to make?  If e.g. you want to modify every string value, you could load your JSON into a `JObject` and then use the answer from [With json.net, is there a shortish way to manipulate all string fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46148971/3744182) to iterate through and remap all the string values.

Comment: Maybe you an create a corresponding model,and convert json to the model with Newtonsoft.Json.